# How to move free space from the middle of a disk with Gnome Disks or blivet-gui

Tags: fedora, partition, gnome-disks

I used to dual boot Windows and Fedora 35, and decided to just run windows in a vm.  I deleted the Windows partitions successfully, but now I have free space in the middle that I can't figure out how to move safely.

Since I don't have a swap partition, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603615/multiple-free-space-disk-partition) doesn't help, and since the partitions are on the same disk, I can't use [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274782/how-to-move-empty-disc-space-between-partitions).

I don't want to use GParted because it's not installed on my Fedora live usb (and other unrelated reasons), so my options are Gnome Disks and blivet-gui.  Is there a way to safely move the free space from the middle of nowhere to my main partition?

**Print `lsblk`**

Return mountpoint for `fedora_localhost-live` (nvme0n1p6).

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
zram0       252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p5 259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p6 259:3    0 350.9G  0 part /home
                                      /
```

[image: blivet-gui screenshot]

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "move" free space. It also doesn't solve anything! You'd still need to tell your / filesystem to use that.

However, your filesystem that you want to extend is btrfs - perfect! You can just add more partitions to the btrfs volume to extend its size, no need to move anything. And since this is an ssd and not a spinning disk, this also has no performance downside at all.

It's quite doable:

1. Use blivet-gui to add a new partition that uses up your free space. Don't format it!
2. Note down the name of that position, e.g., nvme0n1p42.
3. Add the new space to your existing volume: `sudo btrfs device add /dev/nvme0n1p42 /`

That's it! You can use the new space right away.

Comment: Thank you!!  Simple enough, however it threw an error: `/ is not a btrfs...`.  I tried using the path for the Fedora partition, but of course that didn't work.  Could it be because my `/boot`s are efi and ext4?  That leads to another question, but I'm not sure if I should start a new post.  I (probably) don't need 2 `/boot`s, so how do I know which one to remove?

Comment: you need both partitions, one is the EFI boot partition, the other is for your second stage bootloader. Also, note how small they are; what do you care about a single GB? Your screenshot certainly looks like your `fedora_localhost-live` partition is btrfs, according to the table at the bottom! So, you need to replace what I presumed to be its mountpoint, `/`, by where it's actually mounted.

Comment: Not worried about the 1 gig, I just like to keep things clean.  I ran `lsblk` to find the mountpoint, and it's `/home`, but changing that in `device add` threw the same error.  I'll add the log of `lsblk` to the question.

Comment: Lsblk might not be the tool of choice to figure out which filesystem type is mounted where. mount would be!

Comment: I tried using findmnt, /proc/mounts and df.  Only lsblk returned anything.  The other 3 didn't return anything at all.

Comment: so, it's not mounted. So mount it!

Comment: Wait, so I'm doing this while the partition is mounted??

Comment: yes, that's what I said, isn't it?